# Can I use FlatList in FlatList (React Native)?

Tags: react-native

Now I want to build a small library app.
In this app, I am using FlatList.
Then can I use FlatList in a FlatList?
So can I get [this kind of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlbKX.png) with FlatList?
Now I am thinking as follows. Is this possible method?
If this method is possible, how to use it? I wish any sample code even very simple.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.countryList}
    renderItem={({ country }) => (
        <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={this.props.album ? this.props.album.mostDown : []}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('StageTwo')
                }}>
                    <View style={styles.borderImageGroup}>
                        <Image style={styles.borderImage} source={{ uri: item['thumbnailURL'] }} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and it worked perfectly for me.

```
<FlatList
  data={data ? data : []}
  renderItem={({ outerItem }) => (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={outerItem["data"] ? outerItem["data"] : []}
        renderItem={({ innerItem }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("Home", {
              artist_id: innerItem["artistID"]
            })
          }}>
            <View>
              <Text>Inner FlatList</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(innerItem) => innerItem.id}
      />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: hi, i keep getting this error: VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

Comment: @kd12345 is your flatlist inside a scroll view ? if so flatlist musn't be in a scroll view

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use it.

`Editing:` according to your comment I am assuming this will be the data passed down to the FlatList

```
   const FlatListData = [{
      country: 'Country Name', // Which will display on bottom
      artists: [
        {artist_name: 'artistOne_name'},
        {artist_name: 'artistTwo_name'},
        {artist_name: 'artistThree_name'},
        {artist_name: 'artistFour_name'},
       ]
  }]
```

here is an example.

```
 <View>
        <Text>test page</Text>
        <FlatList
            data={FlatListData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View>
                <Text>{item.country}</Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={item.artists}
                    renderItem={({ item2 }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item2.artist_name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item2, index) => index}
                />
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Thank you Waheed, If the data comes from redux - (this.props.album.albums) in this way, then how to use?

Comment: @SatelBill Can you please explain a bit about the structure of the data that you will provide to FlatListt, Nested FlatList will get the data from the item of the FlatList or it has some other source for data?

Comment: It comes from MySQL DB. 
If I add a country(outer FlatList) to the DB, it must be shown to the bottom of the FlatList. And every country contains so many artists. (inner FlatList)
You can reference the image that I post first.

Comment: @SatelBill I have edited my answer according to your above comment.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation. Please check this image.
And please help me.
h t t p:we.tl/t-C2a5O9Ea9G

Comment: I have looked into your image but it's already confusing please share a better example.

Comment: Each country contains 10 artists. After I add a country to the country table, I add artists to the artist table(MySQL) with specified country ID.
Then it must be shown to the list. That's it.

Comment: Please share the mock data that will be passed to the FlatList

Comment: Egypt : (artist1, artist2 ..... artist10)
Tunis : (author1, author2, ....author10)
Iraq   :  (singer1, singer2, .... singer10)
....            ......           ......

Comment: Sorry too late. I added another image, this is DB.  h t t p s :/  / we.tl/t-Gpt7vIbYnb

Comment: Bro, I wanted to help you but this is not the Information I am asking for. I am asking about the JSON response of the Array that you will be pass to the List.